# Making a login box using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me create a login box like this?
I'm trying to figure out how to create a divider and columns.

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
 <div class="container" style="max-width:560px;">
        <div class="row">
           <iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tqBwJld2Sz8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-arrow btn-block" href="/#login"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span translate>Login</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-arrow btn-block" href="/#register"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span translate>Register</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: yes, Using bootstrap

Comment: Use the grid if you are using foundation - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html or bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks. That helped :)

Comment: but your code is ok, thats a good way to do that  you just have to apply some css and the add the input fields

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! Solved it.

```
<div class="container login" style="max-width:560px;">
        <div class="row">
           <iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tqBwJld2Sz8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="row vertical-divider">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-arrow btn-block" href="/#login"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span translate>Login</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="divider-vertical"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-arrow btn-block" href="/#register"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span translate>Register</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
```